# AWS Cognito Generated Credentials are not accepted by API Gateway

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have setup API Gateway Endpoints with authorization enabled as IAM.

First, I tried to access the resource using my own user credentials (key, secret) and it worked.

Then, I've setup Cognito with an Identity Pool. The pool allows both - authenticated and unauthenticated access.
I have generated credentials using PHP SDK:

```
$id = $cognitoClient->getId([
        'AccountId' => 'xxx',
        'IdentityPoolId' => 'xxx', 
    ]);
$credentials = $cognitoClient->getCredentialsForIdentity([
    'IdentityId' => $id->get('IdentityId')
])->get('Credentials');
```

This is able to generate the credentials - `AccessKeyId`, `SecretKey` and `SessionToken` are being returned.

The role I've attached with unauthenticated access is defined like this:

Trust Relationship:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
         "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
       },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "xxx"
         }
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

Inline Policies:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-sync:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:cognito-sync:us-east-1:123456789012:identitypool/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}/identity/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-sync:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:cognito-sync:us-east-1:xxxxx:identitypool/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "apigateway:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't attached any Managed Policy with the role.

Now, after generating the credentials using PHP SDK, I use postman to access the resource (I used postman while using my account creds too). This call gives the following error:

`{"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}`

I am unable to determine what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

For now, I've switched to using the Javascript SDK that can be generated for each deployment.

Using the SDK is solving the problem. One thing I observed is that I've to pass the session token in the SDK which I was not passing (I don't know where to put it) before.

Comment: That was going to be my guess. I don't know if Postman supports temporary credentials, but when using Cognito or any session credentials you need to send the SessionToken in the request. Glad the SDK is working for you!

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR : to get it working with Postman you have to pass your token in a header called `X-Amz-Security-Token`.

First thanks, I was struggling with the same problem until your own answer, which led to me to the solution.

In the README of the javascript SDK you can find :

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
    sessionToken: 'SESSION_TOKEN', //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
    region: 'eu-west-1' // OPTIONAL: The region where the API is deployed, by default this parameter is set to us-east-1
});
```

Ok so you need the token for temporary credentials, it would be nice to see that in the cognito doc instead of here, but ok. I resign to write a javascript version to test, which apparently needs CORS to work. On the page to activate CORS you have the field `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` with default value `Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token`, and there it is.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it tomorrow. By the looks of it, I think it will work. I'll update here.